# How to create a radial column chart using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, radial

I am trying to create a radial column chart using python and can only figure out how to make a polar plot.  I am trying to make something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbdNB.png)

Where the bars do not fan out away from the center.

My current code is:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111,projection = 'polar')

plt.bar(theta, y)
```

but the bars fan out, achieving what is detailed on [matplotlib's site](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_bar.html)

Comment: Did you set the width of the bar to a small number? Depending on the data you could also use `plt.plot` instead

Comment: Also `plt.stem` could be an option to explore in this case.